# How to achieve type inference for a reducer function concisely?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are many examples on typing reducer functions, but they seem too verbose for my liking. I tried to keep it short and simple and wrote my actions and reducer typings as follows:

#### Actions

```
interface Actions {
  VISIBLE: "yes" | "no"
  LOCATION: { x: number; y: number }
}
```

#### Action

```
interface Action<T extends keyof Actions> {
  type: T
  payload: Actions[T]
}
```

Type intellisense for the payload perfectly for the following example:

```
const example : Action<'VISIBLE'> = {type: 'VISIBLE', payload: 'yes'}
```

However, in the following reducer function, even when the type of the action is clear, the type of the payload is not inferred as I expected:

```
const myReducer = (
  state: any,
  action: Action<keyof Actions>
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'VISIBLE':
      const example = action.payload
  }
}
```

I expected the type of `example` here to be inferred as `'yes' | 'no'` but instead the inference is the union of the payloads of all actions:

[image: type inference result for 'example' variable]

What am I missing here in order to make payload type inference work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
interface Actions {
  VISIBLE: "yes" | "no"
  LOCATION: { x: number; y: number }
}

interface Action<T extends keyof Actions> {
  type: T
  payload: Actions[T]
}

// Add custom typings here
type A = {
  [K in keyof Actions] : Action<K> 
}[keyof Actions]


const myReducer = (
  state: any,
  action: A
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'VISIBLE' :
      const example = action.payload
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iAzsgbwChlkA1ASQGUKAhAGQFEAuZAIgE8Jc3kAfdiCxsSyegHkAwqgAqFcQDlWBZAA9WIAK4BbAEbQA3Mg4ad%20qMgC%20Ra0VCRYiFOkw4APDOQRVkEABN8AGsIDiwYNAxsPAA%20QlEwDgAHCFYZUUS4DgAbLDg-Vhco3ABtGQBdGyIiBOS0ZABeONJigGlkUGRg0PDCnFwy5ALI9xbYm2KusIjXPAqqhD6wZG0OACUIP00kC0aAClFcMDhIVjgQDgAaUUQZgqIASgbY4lJcAHdgMAQAC2Rdm6iADoahBHi9SMgEHBcCgAOSUGgMRiwwaiCGQxZeVRwbSJLIoRoAnCAjLZXJ%20UTWSxAA)